# Critique: résumé: design without sacrificing conservatism and content-focus?

Tags: typography, critique, resume

Although I have already asked a résumé question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35567/critique-any-advice-on-the-design-of-my-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9), this is for another resume and a completely different question so I created a second question so as not to distract from the first one.

Essentially I am trying to create a résumé for the **finance/enterprise** field, so I understand the design has to be really simple and conservative here, but elegant and pleasing to look at, at the same time. I used the Baskerville font, but I am open to suggestions for any other serif fonts to use instead. I'm also open to change the secondary color to something else as well. There is more content to be added, so the margins should *not* be an issue. My actual last name lines up nicely with the *2B Systems Design Engineering* subheading.

My main question, and concern, is that I'm wondering how I could maintain the conservative nature of the résumé seeing as though it's for a corporate audience, but at the same time improve readability and aesthetics. I was thinking this could be achieved simply with typography manipulation?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I would play with:

- loose the italic *and* uppercase on the "education", "skills" etc. One will do nicely. And I would imagine that you can skip the ":", as it is pretty obvious what follows.
- I would make the line space bigger and also increase the paragraph
  shifts.
- I would make the indents a *lot* bigger on "experience" and down to the actual employer history. See example here:

[image]

Baskerville is fine, really. Your image is a little measly in resolution, but when I tested this myself, it seems fine. I really see no reason for making it more complicated than necessary. You will be using bold, maybe italic and various sizes (three-four different ones), so it is sensible to stick to one font. Keep it simple.

The colour; I think green works well too. Generally, the most conservative colours are often dark blue/prussian blue/navy/indigo. So green: good. You are conservative with the font; a fresh green is good. IMHO.

Comment: I agree with everything except the depth of the indent. What you have here is outrageous. Three wordspaces, no deeper.

Comment: I love how designers can come up with adjectives like "outrageous" for indents :-D

Comment: @LaurenIpsum hehe - i overdid it, to highlight the area, as it would not apply to other parts of the CV. Maybe I should have been clear on that...

Comment: @Emilie A nine-wordspace indent for 10-point text? "Outrageous" is the only possible description. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using small caps for your first name, use them as well for your last name. 
Try playing with, font size of the headers and sub-headers, & Indenting the content to divide the sections a bit more